# How to plot a 3d graph using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, pde

how to plot a 3d graph with d3.js for  z=x+y .I need to plot graph for partial differential equations.My project involves solving partial diffferential equation and ploting it using a graph

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
    body{
      font-family: sans;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    svg path{
      stroke: #000;
      stroke-width: 1px;
      stroke: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }
    svg{
      border: 1px solid #DED8BF;
      background-color: #f4f4d9;
      width: 700px;
      height: 400px;
    }
    h1{
      font-weight: normal;
      margin: 0;
      padding-left: 5px;
      color: #53483e;
    }
    p{
      margin: 0;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
      padding-left: 5px;
      color: #917e6b;
    }
    ul{
      width: 200px;
      float: left;
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      padding-right: 10px;
    }
    li{
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: #c8ad93;
      padding: 10px;
      margin: 2px;
      color: #fff;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>D3.js Surface Plots</h1>
      <p>Drag graph to change view</p>
      <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
      <script src="surface3d.js"></script>
      <script>
      var yaw=0.5,pitch=0.5, width=700, height=400, drag=false;

      function dataFromFormular(func){
        var output=[];
        for(var x=-20;x<20;x++){
          var f0=[];            
          output.push(f0);
          for(var y=-20;y<20;y++){
              f0.push(func(x,y));
          }
        }
        return output;
      }

      var surfaces=[
        {
          name: 'Dataset 1',
          data: dataFromFormular(function(x,y){
              return Math.sin(Math.sqrt(x*x+y*y)/5*Math.PI)*50;
            })
        },
        {
          name: 'Dataset 2',
          data: dataFromFormular(function(x,y){
              return Math.cos(x/15*Math.PI)*Math.cos(y/15*Math.PI)*60+Math.cos(x/8*Math.PI)*Math.cos(y/10*Math.PI)*40;
            })
        },
        {
          name: 'Dataset 3',
          data: dataFromFormular(function(x,y){
              return -(Math.cos(Math.sqrt(x*x+y*y)/6*Math.PI)+1)*300/(Math.pow(x*x+y*y+1,0.3)+1)+50;
            })
        }
      ];
      var selected=surfaces[0];

      var ul=d3.select('body')
               .append('ul');
      var svg=d3.select('body')
              .append('svg')
                .attr('height',height)
                .attr('width',width);

      var group = svg.append("g");

      var md=group.data([surfaces[0].data])
        .surface3D(width,height)
          .surfaceHeight(function(d){ 
            return d;
          }).surfaceColor(function(d){
            var c=d3.hsl((d+100), 0.6, 0.5).rgb();
            return "rgb("+parseInt(c.r)+","+parseInt(c.g)+","+parseInt(c.b)+")";
          });

      ul.selectAll('li')
        .data(surfaces)
          .enter().append('li')
            .html(function(d){
              return d.name
            }).on('mousedown',function(){
              md.data([d3.select(this).datum().data]).surface3D()
                .transition().duration(500)
                .surfaceHeight(function(d){
                  return d;
                }).surfaceColor(function(d){
                  var c=d3.hsl((d+100), 0.6, 0.5).rgb();
                  return "rgb("+parseInt(c.r)+","+parseInt(c.g)+","+parseInt(c.b)+")";
                });
            });

      svg.on("mousedown",function(){
        drag=[d3.mouse(this),yaw,pitch];
      }).on("mouseup",function(){
        drag=false;
      }).on("mousemove",function(){
        if(drag){            
          var mouse=d3.mouse(this);
          yaw=drag[1]-(mouse[0]-drag[0][0])/50;
          pitch=drag[2]+(mouse[1]-drag[0][1])/50;
          pitch=Math.max(-Math.PI/2,Math.min(Math.PI/2,pitch));
          md.turntable(yaw,pitch);
        }
      });

      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is the javascript for surface.js

```
(function(){
  var Surface=function(node){
    var heightFunction,colorFunction,timer,timer,transformPrecalc=[];
    var displayWidth=300, displayHeight=300, zoom=1;
    var trans;


    this.setZoom=function(zoomLevel){
      zoom=zoomLevel;
      if(timer) clearTimeout(timer);
      timer=setTimeout(renderSurface);
    };
    var getHeights=function(){
      var data=node.datum();
      var output=[];
      var xlength=data.length;
      var ylength=data[0].length;
      for(var x=0;x<xlength;x++){
        output.push(t=[]);
        for(var y=0;y<ylength;y++){
            var value=heightFunction(data[x][y],x,y);
            t.push(value);
        }
      }
      return output;
    };
    var transformPoint=function(point){
      var x=transformPrecalc[0]*point[0]+transformPrecalc[1]*point[1]+transformPrecalc[2]*point[2];
      var y=transformPrecalc[3]*point[0]+transformPrecalc[4]*point[1]+transformPrecalc[5]*point[2];
      var z=transformPrecalc[6]*point[0]+transformPrecalc[7]*point[1]+transformPrecalc[8]*point[2];
      return [x,y,z];
    };
    var getTransformedData=function(){
      var data=node.datum();
      if(!heightFunction) return [[]];
      var t, output=[];
      var heights=getHeights();
      var xlength=data.length;
      var ylength=data[0].length;
      for(var x=0;x<xlength;x++){
        output.push(t=[]);
        for(var y=0;y<ylength;y++){
          t.push(transformPoint([(x-xlength/2)/(xlength*1.41)*displayWidth*zoom, heights[x][y]*zoom, (y-ylength/2)/(ylength*1.41)*displayWidth*zoom]));
        }
      }
      return output;
    };
    var renderSurface=function(){
      var originalData=node.datum();
      var data=getTransformedData();
      var xlength=data.length;
      var ylength=data[0].length;
      var d0=[];
      var idx=0;
      for(var x=0;x<xlength-1;x++){
        for(var y=0;y<ylength-1;y++){
          var depth=data[x][y][2]+data[x+1][y][2]+data[x+1][y+1][2]+data[x][y+1][2];
          d0.push({
            path:
              'M'+(data[x][y][0]+displayWidth/2).toFixed(10)+','+(data[x][y][1]+displayHeight/2).toFixed(10)+
              'L'+(data[x+1][y][0]+displayWidth/2).toFixed(10)+','+(data[x+1][y][1]+displayHeight/2).toFixed(10)+
              'L'+(data[x+1][y+1][0]+displayWidth/2).toFixed(10)+','+(data[x+1][y+1][1]+displayHeight/2).toFixed(10)+
              'L'+(data[x][y+1][0]+displayWidth/2).toFixed(10)+','+(data[x][y+1][1]+displayHeight/2).toFixed(10)+'Z',
            depth: depth, data: originalData[x][y]
          });
        }
      }
      d0.sort(function(a, b){return b.depth-a.depth});
      var dr=node.selectAll('path').data(d0);
      dr.enter().append("path");
      if(trans){
        dr=dr.transition().delay(trans.delay()).duration(trans.duration());
      }
      dr.attr("d",function(d){return d.path;});
      if(colorFunction){
        dr.attr("fill",function(d){return colorFunction(d.data)});
      }
      trans=false;
    };
    this.renderSurface=renderSurface;
    this.setTurtable=function(yaw, pitch){
      var cosA=Math.cos(pitch);
      var sinA=Math.sin(pitch);
      var cosB=Math.cos(yaw);
      var sinB=Math.sin(yaw);
      transformPrecalc[0]=cosB;
      transformPrecalc[1]=0;
      transformPrecalc[2]=sinB;
      transformPrecalc[3]=sinA*sinB;
      transformPrecalc[4]=cosA;
      transformPrecalc[5]=-sinA*cosB;
      transformPrecalc[6]=-sinB*cosA;
      transformPrecalc[7]=sinA;
      transformPrecalc[8]=cosA*cosB;
      if(timer) clearTimeout(timer);
      timer=setTimeout(renderSurface);
      return this;
    };
    this.setTurtable(0.5,0.5);
    this.surfaceColor=function(callback){
      colorFunction=callback;
      if(timer) clearTimeout(timer);
      timer=setTimeout(renderSurface);
      return this;
    };
    this.surfaceHeight=function(callback){
      heightFunction=callback;
      if(timer) clearTimeout(timer);
      timer=setTimeout(renderSurface);
      return this;
    };
    this.transition=function(){ 
      var transition=d3.selection.prototype.transition.bind(node)();
      colourFunction=null;
      heightFunction=null;
      transition.surfaceHeight=this.surfaceHeight;
      transition.surfaceColor=this.surfaceColor;
      trans=transition;
      return transition;
    };
    this.setHeight=function(height){
      if(height) displayHeight=height;
    };
    this.setWidth=function(width){
      if(width) displayWidth=width;
    };
  };
  d3.selection.prototype.surface3D=function(width,height){
    if(!this.node().__surface__) this.node().__surface__=new Surface(this);
    var surface=this.node().__surface__;
    this.turntable=surface.setTurtable;
    this.surfaceColor=surface.surfaceColor;
    this.surfaceHeight=surface.surfaceHeight;
    this.zoom=surface.setZoom;
    surface.setHeight(height);
    surface.setWidth(width);
    this.transition=surface.transition.bind(surface);
    return this;
  };            
})();
```

Comment: D3 can't plot functions directly. You need to generate a set of points using the function and plot those.

Comment: And your problems is ........ . ..............